# How to install Vapor 2 for Xcode 8.2.1 with Swift 3.1

Tags: swift3, vapor, xcode8.2

**What I am trying to do**

I am following the guide to Install Vapor on macOS https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/getting-started/install-on-macos/

**Verify Swift Installation**

```
eval "$(curl -sL check.vapor.sh)"
```

> supported Vapor v 2

**Add Homebrew Tap**

```
brew tap vapor/homebrew-tap
brew update
brew install vapor
```

> Vapor Toolbox: 3.1.4 is installed

My info:

iMac (24-inch, Early 2009)

**OS X** El Capitan - Version 10.11.6

Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)

Toolchain: Swift 3.1 RELEASE 2017-03-27 (a)

https://swift.org/builds/swift-3.1-release/xcode/swift-3.1-RELEASE/swift-3.1-RELEASE-osx.pkg

** **UPDATE** **

*I cloned two repositories* https://github.com/vapor/api-template (b6c7df2) and https://github.com/vapor/web-template (d206163)

> Now I can create a Vapor v2 with Swift 3.1 projects like this:

***API Template***

```
vapor new ApiTemplate --template=https://github.com/ValeriyKliuk/vapor-2-api-template
cd ApiTemplate/
vapor xcode -y
```

***WEB Template***

```
vapor new WebTemplate --template=https://github.com/ValeriyKliuk/vapor-2-web-template
cd WebTemplate/
vapor xcode -y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between the toolbox and the framework. The toolbox is the CLI tool that runs various commands, the framework is the thing you actually build against. If you do `vapor new MyProject` that will create a Vapor 2 project

(Note - I'm pretty sure that Vapor 2 requires Swift 3.1)

Comment: Yes, I have `Vapor Toolbox: 3.1.4` installed. But when I do `vapor new Hello --template=api` from https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/getting-started/hello-world/ it creates `Package.swift` within `// swift-tools-version:4.0` syntax. Why? :)

Comment: Ah because the current template is built with Swift 4

Comment: Under https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/getting-started/hello-world/ it mention `This section assumes you have installed Swift 3.1 and the Vapor Toolbox and have verified they are working.` How to say to the CLI that I would like to use `Vapor v2` or `Swift 3.1`? ;)